# Jacoco - Multi-flavor and Multi build-type Android App unit tests not generating jacoco reports

Tags: android, gradle, azure-devops, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm trying to do a Code Coverage for an Android App in Azure DevOps pipeline (YAML).
The project I'm working is configured to with multi-flavor.

Here's a build.gradle from app module:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            testCoverageEnabled = true
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
            debuggable false
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        STAGING_BR {
            getProps('./config/staging_br.props').each { p ->
                buildConfigField 'String', p.key, p.value
            }
        }
        DEV_BR {
            getProps('./config/dev_br.props').each { p ->
                buildConfigField 'String', p.key, p.value
            }
        }
```

As you can see I've enabled "**testCoverageEnabled = true**", and followed the steps in this article.

https://medium.com/swlh/multi-module-multi-flavored-test-coverage-with-jacoco-in-android-bc4fb4d135a3

No matter how hard I try updating the Groovy for Unit tests, I'm unable to generate the Reports.

Here's the task from Azure DevOps

```
  - task: Gradle@2
    displayName: 'Unit Test'
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: '$(workingDirectory)'
      gradleWrapperFile: '$(workingDirectory)/gradlew'
      gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
      publishJUnitResults: true
      testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'    
      testRunTitle: 'Unit Testing'
      tasks: 'app:testDEVUMReleaseUnitTestCoverage --i --stacktrace --info'
      sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
      sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: 'specify'
      sonarQubeGradlePluginVersion: '3.3'
```

If someone has worked with this situation, can anyone help me on this.

I tried following the steps in this article - https://medium.com/swlh/multi-module-multi-flavored-test-coverage-with-jacoco-in-android-bc4fb4d135a3

The JUnit test reports are not being generated, as well as the Jacoco reports are not generated in app/build/coverage-report

Here the Unit tests are run but the output doesn't give the reports.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee2iy.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!